# streaming with red5 server

Tags: red5, live-streaming

I want to stream with red5 server and I did the following code

```
ffmpeg -i /var/lib/red5/webapps/test/1.flv -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/livestream
```

But when i try to capture the stream it did not give anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

red5 can read flv files directly and convert it to an rtmp stream on port 1935 by default. No need for ffmpeg. Moreover, port 1935 is used by red5 for connecting a flash client, not for pumping in an rtmp stream.